# How to get back text from multi TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I'm developping an application with a friend and we're stuck on a problem...
We want to ask some players' names.
We click on a button to add some TextInput. (Here everithing is OK)
But now, we want to get back the texts we put in.

I tried to save them in state, but I know how to do that with one text, but not with many.

```
 addTextInput = (key) => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    if (textInput.length < 10) {
        *textInput.push(<TextInput style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }} key={key}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ nomJoueur: text })}
        />);*
        Data.addNombreJoueur();
        console.log(nombreJoueurs);
    }
    this.setState({ textInput })
}
```

I tried this to :

```
addTextInput = (key) => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    let nomJoueur = this.state.nomJoueur;
    if (textInput.length < 10) {
        textInput.push(<TextInput style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }} key={key}
            onChangeText={
                (text) => nomJoueur.push(text)
            }
            nomParticipants2={this.state.nomJoueur}
        />);
        Data.addNombreJoueur();
        console.log(nombreJoueurs);
    }
    this.setState({ textInput })
}
```

But with that, I obtain

```
"nomParticipants2": Array [
[23:17:16]           "z",
[23:17:16]           "ze",
[23:17:16]           "zed",
[23:17:16]           "zedz",
[23:17:16]           "zedzx",
[23:17:16]           "zedzxz",
[23:17:16]           "zedzxzx",
[23:17:16]           "r",
[23:17:16]           "rz",
[23:17:16]           "rze",
[23:17:16]           "rzez",
[23:17:16]           "rzezd",
[23:17:16]           "e",
[23:17:16]           "ez",
[23:17:16]           "ezc",
[23:17:16]           "ezcz",
[23:17:16]           "ezczc",
[23:17:16]         ],
```

I really need your help !
Thanks guys

EDIT : Thanks Nerdragen for your help

To fix my problem, I have n differents functions to add inputText :

```
addTextInput = (key) => {
    console.log('Bonjour');
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    let nomJoueur0 = this.state.nomJoueur0;
    let nomJoueur1 = this.state.nomJoueur1;
    let nomJoueur2 = this.state.nomJoueur2;
    let nomJoueur3 = this.state.nomJoueur3;
    ...

    if (textInput.length == 0) {
        textInput.push(<TextInput style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }} key={key}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ nomJoueur0: text })
            }/>);
        Data.addNombreJoueur();
        console.log(nombreJoueurs);
    }
    else if (textInput.length == 1) {
        textInput.push(<TextInput style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }} key={key}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ nomJoueur1: text })
            }/>);
        Data.addNombreJoueur();
        console.log(nombreJoueurs);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few TextInput and don't mind creating extra functions you can always just create an individual function for each component. A cleaner solution is to change your current `onChangeText` to onChangeText={value=> this.setState({value})} where value is the name of the variable in the state. So using the snippet above, if you changed value to `username`, then `this.state.username` would be updated.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.
In fact, I can't create an individual function for each component, because the components are creating by another function (or if i can, I don't know how).
And what you propose works, but only for the last word. It doesn't work for everyone of them.
I don't know how to save them in differents variables but with the same name. (Do you understand whant I mean ?)

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you want multiple inputs to map to one variable. That's highly recommended against since the inputs would reset the variable with every change. To get around this problem, you'll have to set that variable as an array and have each input push a value into that array.

Comment: That's exactly what I want.
But like you say, there's an update at every change, then it save everything (cf the last code : nomParticipants2). I don't know how to get only the last update for each input.

Comment: You can't. It's impossible to get only the last input without knowing the previous inputs. Or else, how can it be the last input? There's 2 solutions I can think of here. 1 is to use an array and push each individual input into a separate index of the array, then just get the final array. But this is messy. 2, because you are only trying to get name, you know the inputs have to be alphabetical. You can force a single input to only accept letters and commas, and force the user to use commas to delimit the names, then just split the string into an array of names.